# Anylogic, using different time unit

Tags: anylogic

I'm having an issue configuring passing time on an Anylogic model: I would like to configure every tick of the model time to be 5 minutes at 1x.
To be clearer, all the things I did were done on the project components shown on the "Projects" tab.
Reading guides and manuals I saw that by clicking on the project root I could configure the time unit in minutes, and this allows me to run it with 1 minute per tick.
I tried to modify the Simulation options setting the "Real-time with scale" at 5, but when I run the experiment it automatically starts at 5x.
Is there any way to achieve my needing?
Thanks a lot.
P

Answer (score 1):

No matter what, the best option to control this, is by doing it programmatically.

```
getEngine().setRealTimeMode(true); // to be sure you are not using virtual mode
getEngine().setRealTimeScale(5);  // 5 would be the 5x, otherwise put a different number
```

For instance, you can run this at 1x when your model starts (on your "on startup" action on your main properties) and with a button, or after some time, you can change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, Felipe! Having the commands to control things is something good! But with your answer, I understood that it's not possible to have a 5 minutes cycle time base. :(